# SQL Server 2012 connection string: can no longer find Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I just installed VS2012 pro RC and SQL server Express 2012. I go to run my app and I get this error:

> The Data Source value in the connection sting specifies an instance of SQL Server
>       that is not installed. To resolve this issue, you can either choose to install
>       the matching instance of SQL Server or modify the Data Source value in the
>       connection string.

I used VS2012 Developer preview for a long time and it used to work just fine. This is the connection string that's in the web.config file:

```
<add name="MySiteDBConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MySiteDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

When I go to Management Studio, I get the error message below. When I go to browse for servers, the list is empty.

[image]

Where's the problem and how do I solve it?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: change the .\SQLEXPRESS for the entire server name.

Comment: @Nudier: where do I find this information?

Comment: You should note that the database you've connected to in Visual Studio is not going to exist on your SQL Express instance. You should create the database in SQL Server (once you've managed to connect to it), and ***STOP*** using the "user instance" and "AttachDbFileName" settings. These are ridiculous and deprecated, and once you're connected you'll be back here asking why the updates you make in Management Studio don't reflect in Visual Studio and vice versa. The reason is they're two different databases.

Comment: No, I am asking where do I find the server name of sql server. I can't even connect to sql server!

Comment: According to Visual Studio, the named instance is called `\SQLEXPRESS`. What @Nudier meant to suggest was to try `Your_Computer_Name\SQLEXPRESS` instead of `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: It occur with you chance name of installed instance of sqlserver. Verify name of instance.

Comment: @Ankit have you read the previous comments? Why would you suggest something tht's already been suggested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure the SQL Server service is running. Visual Studio might be spinning it up for you when you establish a connection using `web.config` and that silly `AttachDbFileName` feature. Check your Services Control Panel applet and make sure that `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` is running. If it isn't running, start it.

While you're there, it can't hurt to make sure the `SQL Browser` service is running.

It also can't hurt to use the proper case. If the instance is called `SQLEXPRESS` then don't call it `SqlExpress` or `SQLExpress`. I've never heard of this breaking connectivity, but be consistent. You might also try other variations just in case:

`(local)\SQLEXPRESS`
`localhost\SQLEXPRESS`
`127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS`
`Your_Computer_Name\SQLEXPRESS`

You should also verify what connection protocols are enabled for this instance. Go to Start > Programs > SQL Server > Configuration Tools > Configuration Manager, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, and highlight `Protocols for SQLEXPRESS` - on the right you should see Shared Memory, Named Pipes, TCP/IP. Which of these are enabled?

**EDIT**

You should [download SQL Server 2012 Express from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx). Install it. Then create a database. Point Visual Studio at that database. Stop, and I really mean ***STOP***, using the `User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName` features. These things are supposed to make development easier but at the end of the day they do little but make development a royal pain in the rear.

Another option is to use [SqlLocalDb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx) for local development. Last month I wrote a [thorough "Getting Started" tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) that may help.

Comment: I know this might sound weird but how do I start sql server, or check that it's running?

Comment: Do you know where the Control Panel is? Under Administrative Tools, there is an applet called Services. In that list is an item called `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`. If that doesn't say `Started`, you need to start it (you can do this by clicking the right-hand side of your mouse and selecting the `Start` option from the menu that appears).

Comment: ok, I'm in the Services part but there's no sql server listed. There's just sql server VSS writer

Comment: Then how could Visual Studio possibly be connecting to it? Are you on the same machine where this connection string in Visual Studio works, or is that a different machine? Have you uninstalled SQL Server since the last time that worked?

Comment: Why is it not there? I just installed it.

Comment: No idea, I wasn't watching you install it, so I have no idea what you did, sorry.

Comment: Go to Start->All Programs->Microsoft SQL Server->Configuration Tools->SQL server configuration Manager .Under SQL Server Services you will see your sql server instance

Comment: @praveen: unfortunately, it's not there; just added screenshot

Comment: Then you need to actually install SQL Server Express. It doesn't get there by magic; perhaps I misunderstand how Visual Studio can use an instance name like that if it doesn't even exist.

Comment: It's already installed; I went through the SQL server Setup. Apparently the problem is that it's not even starting and not listed in the services applet. Not sure what to do now. Nice article BTW!

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. If SQL Server isn't in the Control Panel or the Configuration Manager, then it's not installed. <shrug>

Comment: But I do see a list of about 10-15 program names related to SQL server 2012 in the Uninstall or Change a program window.

Comment: But none of them are SQL Server. If you have a BMW jacket and a BMW keychain, it doesn't mean there's a BMW in the driveway.

Comment: ok, you pointed me towards the solution: I had downloaded Sql Server Express with Tools. I went back to the download page and downloaded Express Only and that did it. Why the "With Tools" option didn't also install sql server itself is a mystery... Thanks for your time!

Comment: The only way With Tools wouldn't have worked is if you didn't choose the database engine services as part of setup. I have successfully installed SQL Express using he With Tools installer.